# Get a new csrf token, even if the current token has expired

Tags: laravel, csrf

Is there a way with Laravel to obtain a new CSRF-token, even when the current token might have expired? I'd like to be able to get a new token without updating the user interface.

I've been experimenting with the Visibility API to check if the browser (only mobile users) gets active again but I soon found out that's not really the issue. If the token has expired, so far I'm unable to get a new one, because I get the token mismatch exception. I want a new token, ignore any mismatch exception, put it in the DOM and let the user continue again.

My user might experience a long idle time but when he/she reactivates the mobile page I want the user to be able to proceed where he/she left off without the need to let them reload the page and provide initial data (like name) again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this script on pages needed a token refresh without refresh page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var csrfToken = $('[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

        setInterval(refreshToken, 3600000); // 1 hour 

        function refreshToken(){
            $.get('refresh-csrf').done(function(data){
                csrfToken = data; // the new token
            });
        }

        setInterval(refreshToken, 3600000); // 1 hour 

    </script>
```

And in your routes/web.php

```
Route::get('refresh-csrf', function(){
    return csrf_token();
});
```

You can also disable csrf_token verifiction on certain routes, creating a middleware, example below :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes

Comment: Hey, that's actually pretty smart I think. I'm not sure if the route callback is executed after the CSRF middleware, but I'll give that a try. I'll still have to hook in the Visibility API in this case. It looks promising! Thanks. If it works I'll accept your answer. +1

Comment: No problem, let me know if the solution works for your problem